# * method working normall but not with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, http-headers

So, I am setting up a RESTful API and all seemed to be going fine.

It can successfully do a PUT request to the local server with postman:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, LOGIN, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 299
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 14 Sep 2013 17:56:28 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) PHP/5.3.19
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.19
```

But when using ajax with the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: SD.AJAX+'users?uname=jamie&pword=jamie',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'login',
        data: {
            'uname':'jamie',
            'pword':'jamie'
        },
        crossDomain: true
    });
```

I get these errors:

```
OPTIONS http://sexdiaires.local/users?uname=jamie&pword=jamie 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery.js:8526
OPTIONS http://sexdiaires.local/users?uname=jamie&pword=jamie Method LOGIN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods. jquery.js:8526
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sexdiaires.local/users?uname=jamie&pword=jamie. Method LOGIN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.
```

Why, would using ajax make any different, although I must admit the headers recieved are different for some reason :/

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Sat, 14 Sep 2013 18:00:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) PHP/5.3.19
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.19
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=36an511ifo3jsu6uh6a1fqoc82; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sd.local
Content-Length: 3562
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: because you are not specifying that you want to do a put request. jQuery can't know a head of time without you telling it what kind of request to do (default is get). [read the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to find out how to do a put request.

Comment: Yes indeed, i didn't mean to write PUT in the title, it was just something everybody would know. In this case I am actually wanting to use LOGIN as the method.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's because `type: 'login'` isin't a valid HTTP method.

From [jQuery's doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> type (default: 'GET') Type: String The type of request to make ("POST"
>   or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as
>   PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by
>   all browsers.

Have you tried using `type: 'PUT'`?

Comment: I'll give it a whirl, but what about `PATCH, COPY, PURGE` to just but name a few?